# Записать в файл вывод скрипта в терминал, с помощью Python

Tags: python, linux

Python-программа открывает терминал и запускает в нем скрипт

```
os.system("gnome-terminal -- 'script.sh'")
```

как записать текст работы скрипта в файл или вернуть в програму.

Comment: `os.system("gnome-terminal -- 'script.sh' > log")`?

Comment: не создается файл log, скрипт выполняется, но файла log нет

Comment: В какой папке ищешь файл log?

Comment: нашел файл, не там смотрел. Он пустой, но если просто виполнить команду в командной строке    script.sh > log то он запишется

Comment: Вам надо методы класса Popen использовать.